# Invalid Hotkey error(probable simple fix)

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, autohotkey

I'm getting an invalid hotkey error when I type this in

`^u & i::`

`Send, Hello World`

`return`

I just want the script to activate when I press CTRL+u+i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this would be creating a context sensitive hotkey with `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup> like this:

```
#If, GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P") ;begin context sensitive hotkeys
u & i::
    SendInput, Hello World
return
#If ;end context sensitive hotkeys
```